Проблема в логике опредления победителя и ничьи
Создаю свой проект "крестики-нолики" для упражнения в разных аспектах программирования. После написания бота возникла проблема с логикой игры, так как если заполняются все поля И кто-то выигрывает, то выводит два окна, что игра закончилась ничьей И другим - выиграл игрок N.
public class GameLogic extends HelloApplication {
    private final int[][] pole;
    public boolean allCellsFilled;

    public GameLogic(int[][] pole) {
        this.pole = pole;
    }

    public boolean allCellsFilled() {
        // Проверяем, заполнены ли все ячейки
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                if (pole[i][j] == 0) {
                    return false; // Если хоть одна ячейка не заполнена, возвращаем false
                }
            }
        }
        // Если все ячейки заполнены и никто не победил, возвращаем true
        return true;
    }

    public boolean checkWin(int player) {
        // Проверка строк
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            if (pole[i][0] == player && pole[i][1] == player && pole[i][2] == player) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        // Проверка столбцов
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            if (pole[0][j] == player && pole[1][j] == player && pole[2][j] == player) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        // Проверка диагоналей
        return (pole[0][0] == player && pole[1][1] == player && pole[2][2] == player) ||
                (pole[0][2] == player && pole[1][1] == player && pole[2][0] == player);
    }
}

Эту логику я отсылаю сюда (добавлено после замечания неполноты картины, поэтому проблема ничьи и выигрыша решена, но появилась новая: могут выиграть два игрока одновременно, возникает при игре с ботом)
if (gameLogic.checkWin(currentPlayer) && !gameLogic.allCellsFilled()) {
    ShowGameResult(primaryStage, "Победитель: игрок " + currentPlayer);
}
if (gameLogic.checkWin(currentPlayer) && gameLogic.allCellsFilled())
    ShowGameResult(primaryStage, "Победитель: игрок " + currentPlayer);
if (gameLogic.allCellsFilled() && !gameLogic.checkWin(currentPlayer))
    ShowGameResult(primaryStage, "Ничья!");

Как бы не пытался фиксить это, вводя дополнительные проверки, итог один - ошибка, либо та же проблема.

этот код ничего не выводит, поэтому невозможно сказать, в чем проблема.

Возможный дубликат вопроса: Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в коде Java?

@Эникейщик прошу прощение за упущение.
Дошел до такой схемы:
'if (gameLogic.checkWin(currentPlayer) && !gameLogic.allCellsFilled()) {
ShowGameResult(primaryStage, "Победитель: игрок " + currentPlayer);
}
if (gameLogic.checkWin(currentPlayer) && gameLogic.allCellsFilled())
ShowGameResult(primaryStage, "Победитель: игрок " + currentPlayer);
if (gameLogic.allCellsFilled() && !gameLogic.checkWin(currentPlayer))
ShowGameResult(primaryStage, "Ничья!");'
но теперь с ботом можно выиграть одновременно, но не выйти в ничью и победу

@doflare, не нужно писать код в комментарии, отредактируйте, пожалуйста, свой вопрос.

Наверно надо поменять логику приложения и воспользоваться DRY принципом в программировании, чтобы избегать подобные ошибки.

@RomanC а где я повторяю код? Если он сделан максимально компактно, по моим возможностям

@doflare В коде, который в вопросе.  Или ты не понимаешь DRY принцип?

@RomanC Конкретно в коде, так как я понимаю, что если что-то можно закинуть в функцию, то обязательно сделаю. А то что я кинул не поддается таким техникам, по крайней мере на моем уровне

@doflare Нет, это как раз подсказка для решения твоей проблемы, которую ты сам не понимаешь. Под ответ она не годится, а развивать здесь тематику не имеет смысла.

Зачем проверять gameLogic.allCellsFilled() и наоборот при проверке победы, если на результат это вообще не влияет?

@Эникейщик потому что иначе при игре с ботом может получиться так, что выбьет сообщение ничьи и победы какого-либо игрока

Не может. А если даже и может, то обсуждаемая проверка это все равно не решит. Она ничего не решает.

По представленному коду не совсем понятно, как именно проверяется выигрыш каждого игрока, так как такую проверку следует делать после каждого "полухода".
Выигрывает тот, кто первым заполняет три элемента, и если этого добился игрок, начавший игру, она должна сразу завершиться, а не давать возможность закончить свой полуход второму игроку.
Следовательно, проверка на заполнение всего поля нужна фактически лишь для проверки ничейного исхода (хотя ничью можно вычислить и по-другому).
Таким образом, логику можно переопределить следующим образом:
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
out: while (true) { // внешний цикл для ходов
    for (int player = 1; player < 3; player++) {
        int x, y; // "координаты" ячейки для хода
        do {
            System.out.println("Ходит игрок " + player);
            x = sc.nextInt() % 3;
            y = sc.nextInt() % 3;
        } while (!game.move(player, x, y)); // move возвращает false если ход невозможен
        // вывод состояния поля после корректного хода
        game.print();

        if (game.checkWin(player)) {   // проверка выигрыша после полухода
            System.out.println("Выиграл игрок " + player);
            break out;
        } else if (game.allFilled()) { // никто не выиграл, поле заполнено
            System.out.println("Ничья!");
            break out;
        }
    }
}

Онлайн демо
